# Can one core data entity to have relationships with multiple entities

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a question of this data model. **EntityA** entity have a one to one relationship with **EntityB** entity. Now I have **EntityC** entity which has the same identical **EntityB** object.

My question is can I use same **EntityB** entity with the relationship to **EntityC** entity? Or should i use a separate entity ?

Please advice me on what is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same EntityB entity for both. You probably want to use the same entity for both.

Can a EntityB create multiple EntityA entities? If so, you need to change EntityA relationship attribute to one-to-many

Can a EntityB create multiple EntityC entities? If so, you need to change EntityB relationship attribute to one-to-many

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, currently both relationships are one to one